# Will low priority job in artisan queue stop high priority tas from being executed if low priority job takes long time to complete?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm running artisan queue worker with pm2 and was thinking to run two artisan workers one that could process high priority queue, and the other would process low priotiry, long jobs.

The issue is that pm2 does not allow to run the same script as a separate instance.

I know that I can set priorities here `--queue=live-high,live-low,default`, but my problem is that if low priority job takes 5 mins to complete, I need to be able to process high priority jobs meanwhile

Comment: Not the answer you want to hear, so I write it as comment: Not possible.

Comment: @Namoshek any other solutions? Can I simply run artisan as daemon outside of pm2 manager?

Comment: No idea what pm2 is, but if you can run multiple scripts, just not the same one twice, you might want to wrap the artisan command in two shell scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Laravel Documentation:

> ### Background Tasks
>
> By default, multiple commands scheduled at the same time will execute
>   sequentially. If you have long-running commands, this may cause
>   subsequent commands to start much later than anticipated. If you would
>   like to run commands in the background so that they may all run
>   simultaneously, you may use the runInBackground method:

```
$schedule->command('analytics:report')
         ->daily()
         ->runInBackground();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#background-tasks